# How to avoid duplicate code if two classes extending different classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance, code-duplication

I have two classes which extend two different base classes. Those classes setup custom environment.

The are three methods common in both the classes: `prepare()`, `setup()` and `teardown()`.
Each method overrides base class method. (Also they have `super()` calls.) Also `ExtendedBase` extends `Base`.

**First class**:

```
ClassA(Base):
    def __init__(self, args):
        super().__init__(args)

        self._private = OtherClass()

    def prepare(self, args):
        super().prepare(args)
        self._private.prepare()

    def setup(self, args):
        super().setup(args)
        self._private.setup(self._smth, args)

    def teardown(self):
        self._private.teardown()
        super().teardown()
```

**Second class**:

```
ClassB(ExtendedBase):
    def __init__(self, args):
        super().__init__(args)

        self._private = OtherClass()

    def prepare(self, args):
       super().prepare(args)
       self._private.prepare()

    def setup(self, args):
       super().setup(args)
       self._private.setup(self._smth, args)

    def teardown(self):
       self._private.teardown()
       super().teardown()
```

Is this a way to avoid duplicate methods?
I thought about  multiple inheritance with the `Environment` class which will contain duplicated methods, but am puzzled about how to implement this and if it is a good idea at all.

*Edited*: Unfortunately I couldn't do anything with classes hierarchy. `ClassA` and `ClassB` should inherit corresponding classes and override or use the parent's method.

Comment: Maybe you could invert your class hierarchy and put those three methods into a common (abstract) super-class of those two superclasses (which would then be the classes you use, no more need for ClassA and ClassB)

Comment: If the three methods are the only public methods of the base classes, you could use composition instead of inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This look a lot like a typical case to use class mixin:

```py
class BuildMixin:
    def __init_(self, args):
        super().__init__(args)
        self._private = OtherClass()

    def prepare(self, args):
        super().prepare(args)
        self._private.prepare()

    def setup(self, args):
        super().setup(args)
        self._private.setup(self._smth, args)

    def teardown(self):
        self._private.teardown()
        super().teardown()

class ClassA(BuildMixin, Base):
    pass

class ClassB(BuildMixin, ExtendedBase):
    pass
```

---

For illustration purposes here are a bunch of dummy classes that follow your example and use mixin. From your question it is not clear what `OtherClass` should be, but it seems it also has the `prepare`, `teardown` and `setup` methods:

```py
class OtherClass:
    def prepare(self,arg):
        print('OC perparing')
    def teardown(self):
        print('OC tearing down')
    def setup(self, smth, args):
        print('OC setting up')

class Base:
    def __init__(self, args):
        print('Base init')
        self._smth=args
    def prepare(self,arg):
        print('Base perparing')
    def teardown(self,):
        print('base tearing down')
    def setup(self,args):
        print('base setting up')

class ExtendedBase:
    def __init__(self, args):
        print('ExtBase init')
        self._smth=args
    def prepare(self, arg):
        print('ExtBase perparing')
    def teardown(self):
        print('ExtBase tearing down')
    def setup(self, arg):
        print('ExtBase setting up')

class BuildMixin:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        super().__init__(arg)
        self._private = OtherClass()
    def prepare(self, args):
        super().prepare(args)
        self._private.prepare(args)

    def setup(self, args):
        super().setup(args)
        self._private.setup(self._smth, args)

    def teardown(self):
        self._private.teardown()
        super().teardown()

class  ClassA(BuildMixin, Base):
    pass

class ClassB(BuildMixin, ExtendedBase):
    pass
    
a = ClassA(1)
# prints:
# Base init
b = ClassB(1)
# prints:
# ExtBase init
a.prepare(1)
# prints:
# Base perparing
# OC perparing
b.prepare(1)
# prints:
# ExtBase perparing
# OC perparing

# and so on...
```